# MySQL and Symfony2: Exceptions and Hair Loss

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been attempting pretty much all day to get Symfony2's Doctrine configuration screen (e.g. `/app_dev.php/_configurator/step/0`) to connect to my locally running MAMP-provided MySQL instance. I've spent the day reading about sockets, skip-networking, and every other possible scenario but I'm at a loss. This is the error that you have most certainly seen before:

```
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL
server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

And here are the various ways I have tried to correct this maddening problem:

- I verified that I can indeed connect on the command line to both localhost and 127.0.0.1 using the `mysql` command. I made sure the ports were both filled in and not so I could see the results of an actual error.
- I checked the socket while I was in there via `SHOW variables LIKE 'socket'` and saw it pointed correctly to my MAMP socket.
- I've oscillated between the MAMP default ports and the standard MySQL ports (3306) just in case it was a weird port thing.
- I made sure my `/var/mysql` and `/tmp/mysql` `mysql.sock` files were correctly symlinked to MAMP.
- I commented out the skip-networking lines in MAMP's configuration file.
- I toggled the "Allow Network Access" in every configuration possible
- I added the line, `unix_socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`, to my `config.yml` file just in case my symlinking trickery failed me.
- I've done several rain dances and other tribal spells I read in a magazine trying to get this to connect.

I'm no stranger to development and MySQL but this has become a lost cause. Any help would be appreciated and rewarded with my unflinching respect for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code `2003` means "Can't connect to MySQL server", you can try to use the following methods.

Check your config file, is the `parameters.yml` can be access ? If you are on linux, just `sudo chmod 777 /path/to/parameters.yml`, and the mysql connection config parameters looks like this:

`parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1  or localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: yourdbname
    database_user: youraccount
    database_password: yourpassword`

Try to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`;

Comment: Brilliant. It appears the GUI wasn't passing my parameters to the .yml file. Once I filled them in manually and changed permissions (I used 755 to be a little more safe) it all worked a treat. Thank you so much!